# How to save two worksheets to pdf in separate locations?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to save Sheet1 (named Werk)to savelocation1 and Sheet2 (named Klant) to savelocation2.

With this script Sheet1 & Sheet2 will both be saved to savelocation1 and savelocation2.

```
ActiveWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False

Dim Path As String
Dim filename1 As String
Dim filename2 As String
Dim savelocation1 As String
Path1 = Blad1.Range("N67")
Path2 = Blad1.Range("N66")
filename = Blad1.Range("N68")

savelocation1 = Path1 & filename
savelocation2 = Path2 & filename

'Save active workbook as PDF
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:=savelocation1

    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    filename:=savelocation2
```

Comment: Change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Werk")` and `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Klant")`?

Comment: This was the solution!   So easy.   Thx!